# Why does Android App is In Review state even after a week?

Tags: google-play-console, prelaunch

> Channel Uploaded : **Closed Testing**
>
> Managed Publishing **On**
>
> Current status **In Review** (More than a week passed)
>
> Pre-launch Report has 2 security issues

But as for this, we can still publish without fixing pre-launch report errors

How do we know if our app is rejected? (Currently it's still showing In Review).

Comment: was your app published already? :)

Answer (score 7):

You Just need to wait, some updates raise some issues automatically and need a human review, there are a long queue for human review, it could take up to 2 weeks.

It is usually due to the nature of your app content, it happened to me 3 times, the 1st one was a political app for elections, the 2nd was a telemedicine app in COVID-19 time and the 3rd was for a kids app.

It is normal do not worry about it, and it does not happened every time you release an update.

If it was rejected you will receive an email detailing the issue.

Comment: My update for app is in review for a month now

Comment: Same for me. I'm waiting for 3 weeks now

Comment: It actually happens pretty randomly and has usually nothing to do with the content. It might be a new policy, new release after a while or anything that raises a flag.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is user safety.
you have to provide add privacy policy in your app contain and fill user safety form.

Many developer face this kind of problem

Comment: This can be added as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is google new policy, you have to wait for minimum of one and half week.

Comment: can you provide your source?

Comment: Here you can read documentation and step-by-step tutorial 
"https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859455?hl=en

Comment: This is wrong. I just uploaded a APK and it only took 1-2 days to review. The link doesn't say anything about 1.5 weeks. You should delete this, it's not even misleading, it's incorrect.

Comment: AMM, It's not incorrect. Some of my apps took only one day to publish, but some of my apps took almost 6 days to publish. But now whenever I publish a new release, almost take 5 hours; My play store name is "Blue Lock Solution". mail:zainshahidbuttt@gmail.com.

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?hl=en
in this link please read the paragraph named "Standard publishing"